# Hosting a static Node.js page

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, nginx

I'm trying to learn about Node.js and I have written a simple Node.js [page](http://35.163.71.34:3000/) with express and ejs by following a guide at Lynda.com. I have the page hosted on an Amazon AWS server and have Nginx installed. I can access the page at IP:3000 when I'm running the node app. I have also set up Nginx following several different guides to redirect the servers IP/ to port 3000. However when I try and access the page at IP/ none of the images or the CSS show up.

I have set up some webpages in the past for school using Ruby on Rails and I'm assuming that this is a development vs production issue. Most guides/instructions I find just show setting up Nginx for a simple hello world app without any images or CSS. Can someone direct me to the proper resource to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

Edit: Here are my app.js and my two routes
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var reload = require('reload');
var app = express();
var clientFile = require('./data/clients.json');
var instructionFile = require('./data/instructions.json');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('clientData', clientFile);
app.set('instructionData', instructionFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './views');

app.locals.siteTitle = 'Roux Meetups';

app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(require('./routes/index'));
app.use(require('./routes/instructions'));

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

reload(server, app);

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

route 1

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var clients = req.app.get('clientData');
  var clientPhotos = clients.images;
  var clientAddresses = clients.sites;

  res.render('index', {
    pageTitle: 'Home',
    clients: clientPhotos,
    sites: clientAddresses,
    pageID: 'home'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

route 2

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/instructions', function(req, res) {
  var clients = req.app.get('clientData');
  var clientPhotos = clients.images;
  var clientAddresses = clients.sites;

  var instructions = req.app.get('instructionData');
  var instructPhotos = instructions.images;

  res.render('instructions', {
    pageTitle: 'Instructions',
    clients: clientPhotos,
    sites: clientAddresses,
    instructs: instructPhotos,
    pageID: 'instructions'
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I also have only edited my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default for nginx with the following

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen[::]:80 default_server;

root /var/www/html;

index index.html index.html index.nginx-devian.html;

server_name _;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
}
}
```

Comment: did you inspect element on browser ? 
inspect it see the location of photo css and then you will understand the problem \

Comment: or try this server configuration
`upstream nodejs {
    server localhost:3000;
}

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name localhost;
    root ~/workspace/test/app;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @nodejs;
    }

    location @nodejs {
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header Host $host ; 
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}`

Comment: Is that server configuration for the nginx configuration? Why would the relative image/css locations work fine if I go to IP/:3000 and not when I go to IP/ and have nginx redirect to port 3000? I'm trying to understand exactly how this all works together but am missing something key it seems.

Comment: We can't really help you without seeing your Express code and the routes you have defined with it and perhaps the nginx configuration too (if you're expecting nginx to serve static pages).  Express serves NO files by default.  Every file, static or otherwise, that you want it to serve MUST be covered by a route definition.  `express.static()` can be used to define a path to automatically serve static files if you want.  Or, nginx can be configured to serve static files too.

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was that my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default was configured way wrong. I had edited it with garbage and totally forgotten that. Leaving this up though in case anyone else has a similar question. The correct nginx configuration I got from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04